# Can Kendo UI chart legend automatically remove empty series?

Tags: charts, kendo-ui

I have Kendo UI chart (defined in a razor view).

I haven't been able to find anything in the documentation, is it possible to setup the legend to ignore empty series from the chart data or am I forced to add only the relevant series to the chart data?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While not an option in the legend, there is an option in the series objects: [visibleInLegend](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/dataviz/chart#configuration-series.visibleInLegend), this can be set dynamically against a collection or another logical test, e.g.:

```
new {
    category = "Some Category",
    value = Model.SomeCollection.Count,
    color = "#FF9900", //Amber
    visibleInLegend = Model.SomeCollection.Count > 0
},
```

Comment: can you tell how can i acess these attributes i cant see such attributes currently.

Comment: @ImranJawaid http://docs.kendoui.com/api/dataviz/chart#configuration-series.visibleInLegend